# R gridExtra: modify theme on the fly for a single tableGrob?

Tags: r, themes, gridextra

I read Baptiste's excellent explanation of gridextra's tableGrob functions here: https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob

From his section on Aesthetic formatting:

```
tt1 <- ttheme_default()
tt2 <- ttheme_minimal()
tt3 <- ttheme_minimal(
  core=list(bg_params = list(fill = blues9[1:4], col=NA),
            fg_params=list(fontface=3)),
  colhead=list(fg_params=list(col="navyblue", fontface=4L)),
  rowhead=list(fg_params=list(col="orange", fontface=3L)))

grid.arrange(
  tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt1),
  tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt2),
  tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt3),
  nrow=1)
```

I wonder is it possible to modify a theme "on-the-fly" for a particular tableGrob, e.g., something like:

```
grid.arrange(
  tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt1 + theme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(cex=0.7))),
  tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt2),
  tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt3),
  nrow=1)
```

This last block of code does NOT work, but what I wanted to do was modify theme "tt1" on the fly to change the core text size JUST for the first tableGrob, WITHOUT permanently changing the theme "tt1".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Themes appear to be just lists. You can update properties of lists with `modifyList`. For example

```
grid.arrange(
  tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=modifyList(tt1, list(core=list(fg_params=list(cex=0.7))))),
  tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt2),
  tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt3),
  nrow=1)
```